# JQuery - How do I count the number of elements selected by a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $().fadeOut() to fade items out in a list ( < li> < /li>). When the list is empty I wish to hide a parent object.

I plan on doing this by checking in my trigger event that fades the list if the count of the objects is 0 then hide the parent element. I can use the fadeOut callback to remove the elements if necessary.

The to the point question:
**How do I select li tags inside a ul and then get the total count of them using jquery?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('ul > li').length
```

A more elegant way to do it would be to write

```
$('ul:empty').fadeOut();
```

If the `ul` is not empty, the selector won't match anything, and the code will do nothing.

You may need to write

```
$('.SomeContainer:has(ul:empty)').fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thank you that is much more elegant.

Answer (score 11):

use .length

```
$('ul li').length // gives you back all li's in your ul
$('ul > li').length // give just the first children li's
```

so in order to hide your parent you can use it this way:

```
elements = $('ul > li')

if (elements.length) {
   elements.fadeOut()
}else{
   elements.parent().fadeOut()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `.length` against the jQuery collection.

```
var $elements = $('ul#myUlElement').children('li');
alert($elements.length)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you would use `$('ul#myUlElement').children('li')` instead of `$('ul#myUlElement > li')`?