# count elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery - How do I count the number of elements selected by a selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686390/jquery-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-elements-selected-by-a-selector)

I know you can determine if an object exists using `var nextfooter = $('footer.newcontent')[0];`
but using the same sort of syntax could I return the number of elements found?

Comment: Not unless you define a function called `$` that lets you do that.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? `$` is not a native JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('selector').length` or `$('selector').size()`

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
var numberOfElements = $('elementSelector').length;
```

Reference:

- [`length` at the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can retrieve the number of objects found using the size function:

```
var nextfooter = $('footer.newcontent');
var count = nextfooter.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
var count = $('footer.newcontent').length;
```

References:

- Calling the jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/
- Getting data from the jQuery result object: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery