# How to get the number of jQuery elements returned from a matched condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery filter on a set of elements that check to see which items are under the value of 90 and over 100. What I want to do is also get the number of items that match those conditions and eventually save them for output somewhere else on the page:

```
$("#dtarget li").filter(function()
{
    if (parseInt(this.innerText) < 90)
    {
        $(this).css("color","red");
    }
    else if (parseInt(this.innerText) > 100)
    {
        $(this).css("color","gold");
    }
});
```

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript, so be easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - How do I count the number of elements selected by a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686390/jquery-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-elements-selected-by-a-selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/length

You can call `.length` on a jQuery object to get the number of DOM elements it contains.

```
//this will return a jQuery object with elements who's value is less than 90
var less_than_90 = $("#dtarget li").filter(function()
{
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (parseInt(text) < 90)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

//then you can get the number of DOM elements within the jQuery object created above
var less_than_90_count = less_than_90.length;
```

This can then be done for anything greater than 100 as well.

Notice that I removed `this.innerText` in favor of `$(this).text()` since you are already using jQuery you might as well get all you can out of it.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/acyZC/1/

Comment: `innerText` is not available in all browsers anyway (I think Firefox uses `textContent`).

Answer (score 1):

i would just add a counter for each one

```
var redCounter = 0,
    goldCounter = 0;

$("#dtarget li").filter(function() {
    if (parseInt(this.innerText) < 90) {
        $(this).css("color","red");
        redCounter++;
    }
    else if (parseInt(this.innerText) > 100) {
        $(this).css("color","gold");
        goldCounter++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work:

```
var count = $("#dtarget li").filter(function()
{
    if (parseInt(this.innerText) < 90)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (parseInt(this.innerText) > 100)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}).length;
```

EDIT: `return` IS a restricted item. What was I thinking.

Comment: var return might not be the best since 'return' is a keyword

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand the purpose of `.filter()`.  It is used to reduce the number of items in a given jQuery object according to some criteria or function.  If using a function as the argument to `.filter(fn)` as you are, then you return true from the filter to include an element in the final set and you return false to remove it.  You are doing neither.

If you just want to iterate over a jQuery object, use `.each()`, not `.filter()`.

To save the results of your jQuery object, you just assign it to a variable like this and to iterate you use `.each()`:

```
var $targets = $("#dtarget li").each(function()
{
    if (parseInt(this.innerText) < 90)
    {
        $(this).css("color","red");
    }
    else if (parseInt(this.innerText) > 100)
    {
        $(this).css("color","gold");
    }
});
```

You can then refer to it later using the variable $targets and you can find out how many elements are in that jQuery object with $targets.length.  For example:

```
if ($targets.length > 1) {
    $targets.css("padding-left", "10px");
}
```