# get number of li and assign it to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` as navigation with a few `li` elements.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Although I got the same amount of `div` elements, that I can target with `.scrollTo( "number of div" )`, starting by `0`. I could do it on my own this way:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").on('click', function(){
   sliderInstance.goTo(0);
});
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").on('click', function(){
   sliderInstance.goTo(1);
});
$("ul li:nth-child(3)").on('click', function(){
   sliderInstance.goTo(2);
});
$("ul li:nth-child(4)").on('click', function(){
   sliderInstance.goTo(3);
});
```

But that seems to be neither smart nor efficient. Imagen I have about twenty `div` and `li` elements. Is there a good tweak combining `.size()`, `.length()` or something else I am not aware of?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686390/jquery-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-elements-selected-by-a-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for diversity:

```
var $li = $('ul li').on('click', function (event) { 
    sliderInstance.goTo($li.index(this));
})
```

Comment: thanks, that works absolutely perfect! I have edited your answer to fit my although edited question to make it easier to understand!

Answer (score 0):

i would use onclick event

```
<ul id="navigation">
 <li onclick="scrollTo('#yourTargetAnchor1')"></li>
 <li onclick="scrollTo('#yourTargetAnchor2')"></li>
 <li onclick="scrollTo('#yourTargetAnchor3')"></li>
 <li onclick="scrollTo('#yourTargetAnchor4')"></li>
</ul>
```

you can also generate it, but in most cases a hardcoded navigation is not too bad. to generate it i would do like this:

```
var navArr = $('#navigation').children().length;
for (var i = 0; i < navArr; i++) {
  $('#navigation').children()[i].click(function(){
    scrollTo('#yourTargerAnchor'+i);}}
```

not tested but should do the job. hope i could help ;)

Comment: This will work, but in a real life situation I would definitely use an `<a>` tag and event capturing. That way your menu will never break, even for users without JavaScript.

Comment: yea but using an a tag would be just the same, of course you've had to bind the clock event at the a tags in that case